# TypeError: str takes exactly 2 arguments error

Tags: python, string, class

I'm having an issue with getting the output I need. I am using a module (called q3.py) with 3 defined classes: Student, Module and Registrations and implementing it into another file with the following details:

```
#testq3.py
from q3 import *

james = Student('james')
alice = Student('alice')
mary = Student('mary')

agm = Module('agm')
ipp = Module('ipp')

r = Registrations()
r.add(james,agm)
r.add(alice,agm)
r.add(alice,ipp)

mstr = ''
for m in map(str,r.modules(alice)):
    mstr = mstr+' '+m
print(alice, 'is doing the following modules:', mstr)
sstr = ''
for s in map(str,r.students(agm)):
    sstr = sstr+' '+s
print(agm, 'has the following students:', sstr)

print(r)
```

And then here is my q3.py file...

```
class Student:    
    'Class to define student details'
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __str__(self, name):
        return (self.name)
    def __iter__(self, name):
        return iter(self.name)

class Module:    
    'Class to define module codes'
    def __init__(self, modules):
        self.modules = modules    
    def __str__(self, modules):
        return self.modules
    def __iter__(self, modules):
        return iter(self.modules)


class Registrations():
    'Class telling us what modules students are taking'
    def __init__(self):
        self.reglist = []
    def add(self, students, modules):
        self.reglist.append((students, modules))
    def students(self, modules):
        for x in self.reglist:
            if x[1] == modules:
                print x[0]
    def modules(self, students):
        for y in self.reglist:
            if y[0] == students:
                print y[1]
```

I keep getting errors such as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  for m in map(str,r.modules(alice)):
File ".....", line 37, in modules
  print y[1]
TypeError: __str__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

So I added in **str** and also **iter** as I kept getting argument 2 iteration errors as well. Where am I going wrong? I just want the output to be the same as that in the bottom of testq3.py. Please help?? I'm pretty sure I have plenty of str/iter errors but there must be something else that I'm missing as I'm not getting anywhere near the output I want despite playing around with it for ages. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You should remove your edit that asks a second question, and then ask that second question in another question.  As it stands right now with your edited question, your title makes no sense and the answers make no sense.  It's considered bad form to do this... just ask a second question.

Comment: Sorry I'm new and had no idea, I'll remember for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `__str__` methods expect an additional argument but Python doesn't pass that when printing the object.

For example:

```
def __str__(self, modules):
    return self.modules
```

You need to ensure all `__str__` methods have `def __str__(self):` as signature. For example:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.modules
```

Comment: ah what would you suggest I should change it to?

Answer (score 1):

Your `__str__` and `__iter__` methods are taking an unnecessary `modules`/`name` argument. Python won't pass this from the `str` function, and you aren't using it, so just delete it from the argument list of those methods.